# How to use two #imports?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, import, uialertview

I am making an app in which a view controller needs to dismiss a UIAlertView when the user presses the home button. Therefore I need to do this through the app delegate. This view controller's class also needs the app delegate for many other things, so I have a #import in its header file. Up until now I have been using @class in the app delegate for something else, but now I need a #import so that I can call the appropriate method on the view controller. How do I avoid a #import loop? Is there another way of going about this?

Thanks.

Comment: You are going about this all wrong. See the latter part of the answer by "code0100fun". Have your view controller register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`. If the view controller class is showing the alert view, it should be the class that dismisses it. It makes for a fragile design when so many things depend on each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you actually need the full definition in the header, use `@class` in the .h file, and `#import` in the .m file where you actually call the method.

The only time you really need to use `#import` in a header file is if the imported header defines your superclass.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the reason you are concerned with loops is because your app delegate knows alot about your controllers and your controllers now need to call some method on your app delegate. I don't like having a heavy app delegate, so I tend to offload as much as I can onto service and utility classes. If there is something that the app delegate absolutely must do, then make a service class that is a singleton and have your app delegate set itself as the delegate for that service (through a protocol of course). Now your controllers can call this service to do something that usually requires you to call the app delegate.

Also keep in mind that you can use the notification center to listen for many of the events in the app delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

So you may not have to talk to the app delegate at all.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the #import loop you have to follow the following example

let suppose you have 2 files which are as follow

ABC.h
ABC.m
&
XYZ.h
XYZ.m

now you can import "XYZ.h" in "ABC.h" by simply putting #import XYZ.h on the top in ABC.h

but if you want to import "ABC.h" in "XYZ.h" then you can not import it by using "#import". this will create loop.

To avoid this put @class ABC; right above the @interface XYX in "XYZ.h"  and then put "#import ABC.h" in "XYZ.m"

this will work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

`#import` will guard against multiple includes. So not to worry about it. In an ideal world, and just follow convention, you would use `@class` in your header files import the required class in your implementation file.

Comment: `#import` will guard against multiple includes, but it will not resolve circular dependencies. `@class` is the only way around that.